# Returning to form and not showing users name after logging in

Tags: php, html, forms, session

I am creating a website where users will be able to log in and then their name will be placed in the box where they previously logged in, in my case it will say "You are logged in". Here is a before and after screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of index.php page, before and after attempting to log in.]

The session at the moment returns to the log in form after you attempt to log in, it does not show the "You are logged in" statement. Below is the code for the index.php page:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sean Coyne's Food Shop</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="description" content="Welcome to Sean Coyne's Food Shop" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Sean Coyne's Food Shop" 
            title="Sean Coyne's Food Shop" width="400px" height="70px"/>

        <div id="login">
            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>
            <h2>You are logged in</h2>
            <?php } else{ ?>

            <form action="" method="post">
            <label>UserName :</label>
            <input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text">
            <label>Password :</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="**********" type="password">
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
            </form>

            <?php }?>
        </div>

        </div>

        <div id="nav">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="food.php">Food</a></li>
                <li><a href="drink.php.html">Drink</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="findus.php">Where to find us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <h1>Welcome to Sean Coyne's Food Shop</h1>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your code to create the session?

Comment: I assumed the session_start(); created the session? I'm very new to sessions

Comment: You'll need to do $_SESSION['username'] = 'someusername' in order for If(isset($_SESSION['username'])) to trigger.

Comment: We need to see the authentication success code.  Once authentication succeeds, you need to declare $_SESSION variables for later reference.

Comment: No idea, you didn't provide the actual code. My guess is that you didn't set $_SESSION['username'] correctly.

Comment: see the `else{...}` and you'll see for yourself what shows up. session array empty.

Comment: you need to start the session, `session_start()` but you need to add the username to `$_SESSION` array. `$_SESSION['username'] = 'me'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm assuming you haven't created a session, using something like.

```
if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
            // Verification success! User has loggedin!
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            header('Location: nameOfPageYouWantSession.php');
            exit;
        } else {
            echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';
        }
```

Use this script on a new file, so something like logIn.php

So your loggin form should look something like this

```
<form  action="logIn.php" method='POST'>
```

The logIn.php page should be used to make all the checks from the login form. So you should check user and password against your database, then redirect them to the page you want if everything is correct.

*users will be able to log in and then their name will be placed in the box*

You could create a username variable from the session:

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 $username =$_SESSION['username'];
 ?>
```

Then further print that variable

```
<?php echo $username; ?>
```

Comment: No I did not, this goes before                                                                        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>
            <h2>You are logged in</h2>
            <?php } else{ ?>

Comment: Okay, and then in form action should I state logIn.php?

Comment: `header('nameOfPageYouWantSession.php);` that will fail for 2 reasons. http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Welcome back @Fred-ii-, enlighten me:)

Comment: @SmallLegend thanks... see the edit ;-)

Comment: Thank you @Fred-ii- suppose I better update my own code too!

Comment: @SmallLegend  You're welcome. I edited your answer with the right code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- awesome, man I love stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add login logic. Here's how that could look:

```
<?php
/* Login Logic */
$users = [
    [
        'username' => 'Max',
        'password' => 'a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3'
    ],
    [
        'username' => 'Jenny',
        'password' => 'a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3'
    ],
];
 //if we have data from the form submission
if($_POST) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    foreach($users as $user) {
        //matching usernames
        if($user['username'] === $username) {

            //hash form inputed password to try and match with users passwords
            $hashed_form_password = sha1($password);

            //if passwords match
            if($hashed_form_password === $user['password']) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
            }
        }
    }
}
/* End Login Logic */
?>
```

You can place this code anywhere on your page and if you login with the username of 'Max' or 'Jenny' with the password 'test' you will get the message "You are logged in" because you set the 'username' variable in $_SESSION.

It seems like you're are new to building websites in php so even if this doesn't help anyone else out you might get something out of this! :)

Comment: Thank you for this, yes I am very new to building with php, this will really help thank you.